# Unable to change Variable Value in CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am unable to change the model value, whenever I try echo the model name (After changing using if condition) the correct modelname value is displayed but if I try to call it using declared modelname value (ignores the changed value) it uses the declared model name from 'line 8 ' i.e. protected $modelName = '';

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use DateTime; 


class igmc_pat_dat extends ResourceController
{
   
    protected $modelName = '';
    protected $format ='json';
    protected $requestedModule;


public function index(){

$request = service('request');

$fromDate = $request->header('fromDate')->getValue();
$toDate = $request->header('toDate')->getValue();
$requestedModule = $request->header('module-code')->getValue();

$temtodate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $toDate);  
$formatedtoDate=$temtodate->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$ddd= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $fromDate); 
$formatedDate = $ddd->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");


    // $pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate)->where('datetime_of_txn <', $formatedtoDate)->findAll();
    // return $this->respond($pat_rec);


if($requestedModule){
   
    if($requestedModule==1){
$this->modelName = 'App\Models\igmc_pat_1_model'; 
$pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate))->findAll();
 return $this->respond($pat_rec);
    }
    else if($requestedModule==2){
$this->modelName = 'App\Models\igmc_pat_2_model'; 
$pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate)->findAll();
 return $this->respond($pat_rec);
    }
    else{

        echo "  Data Requested";
    }

}

$pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate)->where('datetime_of_txn <', $formatedtoDate)->findAll();
return $this->respond($pat_rec);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your just changing the model name not the actual model. Use the `model` classmember.
From `BaseResource.php`:

```
/**
* @var string|null The model that holding this resource's data
*/
protected $modelName;

/**
* @var object|null The model that holding this resource's data
*/
protected $model;
```

Use it like this:

```
use App\Models\igmc_pat_1_model;
use App\Models\igmc_pat_2_model;

...

       if ($requestedModule) {

            if ($requestedModule == 1) {
                $this->model = new igmc_pat_1_model(); // Change here
                $pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate)->findAll();
                return $this->respond($pat_rec);
            } else if ($requestedModule == 2) {
                $this->model = new igmc_pat_2_model(); // Change here
                $pat_rec = $this->model->where('datetime_of_txn >', $formatedDate)->findAll();
                return $this->respond($pat_rec);
            } else {

                echo "  Data Requested";
            }
        }
```

Furthermore your code is missing a `}` (line 57) and has a `)` (line 40) to much.